# How to find true_dens of numpy array?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, scikit-learn, density-estimation

I am new to data analytics. I am trying to cluster 1D data, i read online and it is usually said that you should not use clustering for 1D data, instead you should use algorithm like kernel density. I used example code from scikit-learn:

```
#Plot a 1D density example
N = 100
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 0.3 * N),
                    np.random.normal(5, 1, 0.7 * N)))[:, np.newaxis]

X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

true_dens = (0.3 * norm(0, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0])
             + 0.7 * norm(5, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.fill(X_plot[:, 0], true_dens, fc='black', alpha=0.2,
        label='input distribution')

for kernel in ['gaussian', 'tophat', 'epanechnikov']:
    kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=0.5).fit(X)
    log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)
    ax.plot(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens), '-',
            label="kernel = '{0}'".format(kernel))

ax.text(6, 0.38, "N={0} points".format(N))

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.plot(X[:, 0], -0.005 - 0.01 * np.random.random(X.shape[0]), '+k')

ax.set_xlim(-4, 9)
ax.set_ylim(-0.02, 0.4)
plt.show()
```

Here I am an unable to understand that how the algorithm is calculating true_dens. what does 0.3 and 0.7 means in this statement:

```
true_dens = (0.3 * norm(0, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0])
             + 0.7 * norm(5, 1).pdf(X_plot[:, 0]))
```

and How can i calculate true_dens if I have numpy array like this:

```
X = np.array((1, 35, 45, 40, 63, 63, 100, 100, 100, 108, 108, 144, 138, 138, 90, 30, 180, 154, 165, 165, 232, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 92, 277, 265, 403, 394, 420, 445, 465, 480, 435, 495, 495, 540, 540, 544, 450, 570, 555, 30, 581, 610, 600, 610, 615, 630, 645, 734, 720, 645, 708, 660, 740, 450, 788, 750, 762, 762, 797, 750, 750, 814, 784, 772, 772, 540, 540, 803, 803, 803, 760, 818, 806, 806, 750, 750, 830, 830, 780, 780, 793, 857, 857, 822, 810, 841, 841, 841, 840, 895, 895, 941, 941, 955, 840, 943, 752, 955, 842, 960, 823, 823, 747, 885, 460, 750, 842, 842, 998, 1005, 1005, 1005, 978, 978, 978, 836, 968, 968, 968, 1015, 500, 1040, 1040, 1040, 1073, 1073, 990, 964, 1032, 1100, 1080, 660, 1030, 1030, 1070, 1070, 1108, 1100, 1027, 1027, 1116, 1111, 1157, 1131, 1115, 1036, 1135, 1090, 1142, 1142, 1170, 890, 1075, 1105, 1236, 1216, 648, 1200, 1110, 1110, 1297, 1272, 1140, 1170, 1170, 1294, 1294, 1195, 1296, 1260, 1090, 1170, 1170, 1020, 1175, 1125, 1105, 1360, 1345, 1140, 1360, 1260, 1350, 1350, 1340, 700, 1320, 1320, 1230, 1230, 1400, 1410, 1396, 1080, 1423, 1380, 1420, 1420, 1430, 1430, 1430, 1430, 1430, 1430, 1435, 1435, 1435, 1380, 1110, 1110, 1438, 1, 900, 900, 900, 1080, 1200, 1320, 1320, 1320, 1080, 600, 562, 1080, 1275, 1275, 1290, 1290, 990, 870, 960, 1260, 480, 1200, 690, 1200, 1320, 1320, 1080, 990, 570, 1165, 120, 120, 120, 720, 1020, 690, 690, 1164, 1164, 1164, 1164, 1410, 1155, 1290, 1260, 915, 1230, 1050, 1200, 540, 660, 660, 1110, 645, 1080, 660, 1380, 1, 1, 1, 780, 1320, 1320, 1020, 1020, 1140, 255, 780, 990, 540, 660, 660, 660, 480, 840, 480, 480, 1260, 480, 480))[:, np.newaxis]
```

Comment: I can't read Python very well. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: It seems as if you copied some code you found elsewhere written for a different purpose without checking what it does. Not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True density is the *theoretical* density of the mixture of gaussians used for drawing random numbers.

You don't have this for real data.